# Computing Time Complexity in code

Tags: time-complexity

I had a doubt in computing the time complexity in the following snippet.

Case 1:-
        for (i = n; i>=1 ; **i=i/2**)
        printf("%d", i);

Case 2:-
        for (i = 1; i < n; **i=i*2**)
        printf("%d", i)

Can I tell, the above codes, will take **O(N/2)** or **O(log N)** time complexity to run against the input?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run it for various values of `n`, how many lines do you get? Does the number of lines seem to be proportional to `log n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes O(log2(n)),just think about this.i=1,then print result is 1,then  2,4,8,16 until 2^x>n,then do math in it,x>log2(n),so the time complexity is O(log2(n))